# NodeJS Concurrent SFTP Downloads Result In Differing File Lengths

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to download multiple files from an SFTP site. When I download them one at a time I get the result I expect but when I download them concurrently with promises the file sizes are often different. I'm using the Bluebird package to be able to download the files with a consistent concurrency. If concurrency is set to 1 I don't have any issues, but anything higher I have issues.

Code:

```
const Client = require('ssh2').Client;
const Promise = require('bluebird');

const connSettings = {
  host: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xx',
  port: 22,
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password',
}

const conn = new Client();
conn.on('ready', function () {
  conn.sftp(async function (err, sftp) {

    const fileNames = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt', 'file4.txt', 'file5.txt', 'file6.txt', 'file7.txt', 'file8.txt', 'file9.txt', 'file10.txt'];

    // Create promise for downloaded file
    const promiseProducer = (fileName) => {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const stream = sftp.createReadStream(fileName, {
            flags: 'r',
            encoding: 'utf8',
            autoClose: true,
            highWaterMark: 65535
          });
          let text = '';
          stream
            .on('data', (d) => { text += d; })
            .on('end', () => {
              console.log(`${fileNames.indexOf(fileName)}:Text Length:`, text.length);
              resolve(text);
            });
        });
    }

    await Promise.map(fileNames, promiseProducer, { concurrency: 2 }) // <-- concurrency of 1 works fine, anything larger causes problems
    conn.end();
  });
}).connect(connSettings);
```

Logs (1 concurrency):

```
0:Text Length: 6160
1:Text Length: 11948
2:Text Length: 18196
3:Text Length: 25400
4:Text Length: 31120
5:Text Length: 37104
6:Text Length: 43544
7:Text Length: 48156
8:Text Length: 54408
9:Text Length: 59640
```

Logs (2 concurrencies):

```
0:Text Length: 6160
1:Text Length: 11948
2:Text Length: 25400
3:Text Length: 31120
4:Text Length: 37104
5:Text Length: 43544
6:Text Length: 48156
7:Text Length: 54408
8:Text Length: 59640
9:Text Length: 59640
```

As you can see the string lengths for each file is different depending on how many I'm downloading concurrently. Any idea why this might be happening? Are the streams getting crossed somehow?

Also worth noting that if I process the promises as chunks I do not get this problem, but then I lose the "constant connections" functionality of the bluebird concurrency limit.

i.e.

```
let promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
  promises.push(promiseProducer(fileNames[i]));
  if (i % 10 === 0) {
    await Promise.all(promises);
    promises = [];
  }
}
await Promise.all(promises);
```